# Id Column having diffrent values in another column need show with specilal value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have one Table Test in this table **Id** column, **FuelId** and **FuelDesc** columns are there.values are like below table,Based on first three columns i need to create out put table like below please help me to get.

```
ID   FuelID   FuelDesc 
100   01       Elec     
101   02       Gas      
102   02       Gas      
100   02       Gas     
101   01       Elec    
103   01       Elec
```

O/P:-

```
ID    Pamenttype       
100   Both        
101   Both       
102   Gas         
103   Elec
```

Comment: have you tried anything yet? Please share if any.

Comment: `SELECT
 ID,
 PaymentType = CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT FuelId) > 1 THEN 'Both' ELSE MAX(FuelDESC) END
FROM test
GROUP BY ID`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CASE` expression, with the help of `COUNT` and `MAX` functions:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    PaymentType = CASE WHEN COUNT(FuelId) > 1 THEN 'Both' ELSE MAX(FuelDESC) END
FROM test
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, CASE WHEN rowCount = 1 THEN FuelDesc ELSE 'Both' END AS Pamenttype
FROM
(SELECT ID, MAX(FuelDesc) AS FuelDesc, COUNT(*) AS rowCount
 FROM mytable
 GROUP BY ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define `Both` as having one record with `FuelID = '01'` and another with `FuelID = '02'`. Assuming {ID, FuelID} is unique in table Test:

```
with BothPaymentTypes as (
    select t1.ID
    from Test t1
    join Test t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
    where t1.FuelID = '01'
    and t2.FuelID = '02'
)
select ID, 'Both' as Pamenttype
from BothPaymentTypes
union all
select ID, FuelDesc
from Test
where ID not in (select ID from BothPaymentTypes)
```

[[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cea22f/2)]

---

Alternatively, you can avoid the self-join with a COUNT and HAVING clause - again assuming {ID, FuelID} is unique:

```
with BothPaymentTypes as (
    select ID
    from Test
    group by ID
    having count(*) = 2
)
select ID, 'Both' as Pamenttype
from BothPaymentTypes
union all
select ID, FuelDesc
from Test
where ID not in (select ID from BothPaymentTypes)
```

[[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cea22f/3)]

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH fuelCount
AS
(
    SELECT ID, COUNT(FuelID) AS fuelCount 
    FROM Test GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT fc.ID, 
CASE 
    WHEN fc.fuelCount > 1 THEN 'BOTH'
    ELSE (SELECT t.FuelDesc FROM Test t WHERE t.ID = fc.ID)
END AS Pamenttype
FROM fuelCount fc
```